# How to connect two different classes

Tags: java, class, inheritance, properties

I would like to get the properties of the `Customer` class to the `Booking` class without using the Extend because a `Customer` is a property of `Booking` and not an extension. How to do it in the best way?

```
public class Booking implements Serializable{

    private String flighttime;
    private String flightlocation;
    private String flightfee;
    private boolean car;
    private boolean insurance;
    private Customer customer;

    ...
}


public class Customer extends Person implements Serializable {

    private String passportID;
    private String consultantname;
    private String consultantsurname;
    private String consulid;

    ....
}

private void savebookingButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Booking customerbooking = new Booking();

    try {
        if (custnameTF.getText().equals("")) {
            throw new EmptyField("Please Insert Customer");
        } else {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
                                          "Bookings/" + custidTF.getText() + ".txt");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            customerbooking.setPersonName((custnameTF.getText()));
            customerbooking.setPersonSurname((custsurnameTF.getText()));
            customerbooking.setPersonID((custidTF.getText()));
            customerbooking.setConsultantname(consnameTF.getText());
            customerbooking.setConsultantsurname((conssurnameTF.getText()));
            customerbooking.setConsulid(considTF.getText());
            customerbooking.setFlightlocation(locationCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
            customerbooking.setFlighttime(timeCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
            customerbooking.setFlightfee(feeCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
            customerbooking.setCar(carRB.isSelected());
            customerbooking.setInsurance(insuranceRB.isSelected());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: book.getCustomer().getPassportID()

Answer (score 2):

You already did it by having Customer as a property.

To get or set properties of Customer using your Booking class instance, you have to write

```
bookingInstance.getCustomer.setSomething(....
bookingInstance.getCustomer.getSomething(....
```

Comment: what I need this for is to use the Booking class and still have access to the Customer properties such as name, Surname etc... Code updated above for further reference.. Thanks

Comment: As it is i cannot use the SetPersonName, SetPersonSurname etc.. because they are in the Customer Class. Thanks @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Comment: @Luke_i Why can't you ? Try. You can.

Comment: Why do you want to call setters on the customer through the booking? That sounds like a gigantic design smell. It would read like you change the customer properties for that one booking, but depending on where these objects come from you might be globally changing the customer properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by creating a new abstract class Reservable (or whatever) that has the 4 fields (and corresponding getters and setters) defined by the Customer class and have both classes (Customer and Booking) extend it. That way, a booking is not a Customer, as they don't extend one another, but they share some of the properties through a common abstract ancestor.

Another way would be to simply define a getter and setter inside the Booking class to access those properties through the customer field.

```
public String getConsulId() { 
   return customer.getConsulId(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :-

```
public Booking (Customer customer){
       this.customer = customer;
}

bookingObj.getCustomer().get..();
bookingObj.getCustomer().set..();
```

That's a composition relationship

Answer (score 0):

Generally you could create getters and setters and get properties by them

Example:
`bookinginstance.getCustomer().getConsultandId()`

But better way is to create business method, which don't brake sOlid principle.

example:
If you want display a customer data for booking create method `displayCustomerData()`

If you want charge customer create in Booking class a `charge()` method.

etc.

```js
public class Booking implements Serializable{
    
    private String flighttime;
    private String flightlocation;
    private String flightfee;
    private boolean car;
    private boolean insurance;
    private Customer customer;
    public void displayCustomerData(){
         System.out.println(customer.getName() + " "+ customer.getSurname());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First create `Customer` obj.

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setCustomerName("name");
customer.setCustomerSurname("surname");
...and so on
```

You already have `Customer` as a member variable in `Booking` class. Now, You can set `Customer` object in `Booking` class using setter method.

```
customerbooking.setCustomer(customer);
```

Or using constructor

```
public Booking (Customer customer){
   this.customer = customer;
}
```

After that you can access `Customer` class fields anywhere in `Booking` class like this :

```
getCustomer().getCustomerName();
```

and outside `Booking` class via

```
customerbooking.getCustomer().getCustomerName();
```

Comment: Yes I encapsulated the field and got the Get and Set. But how will I pin point where I want to store the data such as Customer Name, Customer Surname etc.. if I only have Customer as a property? thanks

Comment: Can you give me an example for the Customer Name please? Can't understand how to implement it. Thanks

Comment: Ok makes sense now.. but where do I type: getCustomer().getCustomerName(); (I already have a Get Customer since I encapsulated the fields) Thanks

Comment: any other methods in `Booking` class where you want `Customer` class properties once you set customer obj in it because it is member variable

Comment: But I dont want to create a new customer.. all I want is to create a booking using the Customer properties. If you see the above code I read from the text boxes and try to set the Customer properties. But like this I cant because I cant access the Customer properties. Thanks

Comment: Either you have to extend Customer class or you have to set Customer obj manually in Booking class. Otherwise, you can not reuse customer fields and your code is going to be repeated

Comment: So I cannot link my classes without an Extend? thanks

Comment: Thats the benefit of inheritance, You can directly access the super class properties to sub class.